# Silverstripe 3 - Force list view of children for one page type

Tags: silverstripe

is it possible to force the children of a defined page type always to show as list?
And if yes, who? Can't figure out who to do this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible, however its pretty trick to get it working properly.
It is not only a lot of work to get it done right, it will also bring certain problems with it which you will have to overcome (eg the Preview Split Screen will not work, you will have to apply some custom javascript I think), so consider this carefully.

Have a look at the silverstripe-blogger module, micmania1 has done a pretty good job there.
He uses a GridField to display the blog children (BlogPosts) if you set the config like this:

```
BlogPost:
  show_in_sitetree: false
```

you can find the module on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/micmania1/silverstripe-blog) and [GitHub](https://github.com/micmania1/silverstripe-blogger)

Comment: I tried to adopt his code. Hiding of the subpages works as expected. I also adopted his code for the gridfield to add pages and here's my problem. every time i click on add page, I get `Undefined index: ReferencePage` my Reference Page is equal to BlogPost. I can't find my mistake

Comment: Of course. I went through the code again, step by step, file by file and compared everything but still the same error -> http://s7.directupload.net/images/140326/nuctb3u4.jpg

Comment: damn, just because of the gridfield name, which was not set to ReferencePage... so I think it's solved.